# Incredibly bad performance joining on subqueries

Tags: sql, mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have the below query:

```
select count(*), 
    json_arrayagg(json_object('ID', o.ID, 'RECEIVERS', r.RECEIVERS, 'PRODUCTS', p.PRODUCTS))
from orders as o
inner join (
    select id,
        json_arrayagg(json_object('firstName', FIRST_NAME, 'lastName', LAST_NAME)) RECEIVERS
    FROM receivers
    group by id
) r on o.id = r.id
  inner join (
    select id,
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('type', TYPE)) PRODUCTS
    FROM PRODUCTS
    group by id
) p on o.id = p.id
where o.ID = "1"
```

which does precisely as I want, it will return a structure such as below:

```
[{
    "ID": "1",
    "ORDERN_NUM": "123",
    "RECEIVERS": [{
        "FIRST_NAME": "Pete",
        "LAST_NAME": "Tyler"
    },
    {
        "FIRST_NAME": "Sarah",
        "LAST_NAME": "Bowden"
    }],
    "PRODUCTS": [{
        "TYPE": "Towel"
    },
    {
        "TYPE": "Pen"
    }]
}]
```

However I have recently loaded my three tables with 18 million rows between them.  2 million in the *ORDERS* table, and 8 in the *RECEIVERS* and *PRODUCTS* each.

When conducting performance testing, I initially saw the `1114 the table xyz is full` error when conducting any queries.  I've since bumped up both `temptable_max_mmap` and `temptable_max_ram` to 12GB and 6GB respectively.  This has allowed the queries to at least complete.

However, when I run a single query, on my Aurora Serverless V2 MySQL RDS DB, with one parameter, the PK from *ORDERS* - which is a foreign key in both *RECEIVERS* and *PRODUCTS* - the query takes FIVE minutes to execute, consumes 100% ACU usage at a 4/16 min/max setting and eats up 40GB of Total Memory Utilisation..

I'm absolute flabbergasted by this, and was wondering if anyone would have any insight into what I may have missed in my query?  I'm fairly sure at this point it's just not very performant, but I can't work out another way to make make it performant, and return what I want.

Would indexing have any impact on this or could it even make it worse?

Comment: If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, why have `GROUP BY id`?

Comment: It's the PK in orders but the FK in RECEIVERS and PRODUCTS.  There can be duplicate `id`s in RECEIVERS and PRODUCTS.  Do you think this is unnecessary?

Comment: explain plan, explain plan, explain plan :: tool number 1 in any performance tuning issue - otherwise we just guess. But note you are joining derived tables, both are grouping, and all tables have millions of source rows. This isn't going to be done in sub-seconds. & also: What indexes exist on the tables?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell zero indexes yet!  And thank you, I will be running explain plan the moment I get back to it!

Comment: Frist things, first. I would push down the predicate `id = "1"` into both subqueries, to `receivers` and also to `PRODUCTS`.